# how can I fix ld not ignoring bad system libraries in favor of my local libraries?

Tags: gcc, ld

I'm trying to build the newest gcc on my redhat box.  I've downloaded and built the latest gmp, mpfr and mpc, per requirements and installed them in my local libraries.  From the config.log file I have the following given below.  Clearly the system version of mpfr is broken, and I want the configure to ignore it.  I have set `LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to my local installation /u/victor/lib.  Since I'm running a configure script, it's not reasonable for me to try to change command line options for gcc.  How do I fix this?

```
gcc -o conftest -g -O2    conftest.c  -L/u/victor/lib -L/u/victor/lib -L/u/victor/lib -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp >&5
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmpfr.so.1, needed by /u/victor/lib/libmpc.so, may conflict with libmpfr.so.4
/usr/bin/ld: __gmpfr_cache_const_euler: TLS definition in /u/victor/lib/libmpfr.so section .tdata mismatches non-TLS definition in /usr/lib64/libmpfr.so.1 section .data
```

What's even more confusing, is that when I compile conftest.c and then

```
gcc -o conftest conftest.o -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp
```

with export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u/victor/lib` it gives the errors below.  I've check libmfpr.so with nm and the three "undefined" symbols are there.

```
/u/victor/lib/libmpc.so: undefined reference to `mpfr_min_prec'
/u/victor/lib/libmpc.so: undefined reference to `mpfr_set_zero'
/u/victor/lib/libmpc.so: undefined reference to `mpfr_get_z_2exp'
```

Comment: Doesn't `configure` have `--with-mpfr=` (or something like that) options?

Comment: @Mat: This should be an answer.

Comment: @Mat The first errors came from using configure with the options --with-mpfr-lib.  It just crapped out in a different way.